# I'm having trouble adding an item to an already alphabetized array

Tags: java, arrays

So far I have what's written below but how would I make sure the item to add returns to it's alphabetized spot?
I'm in a beginner class so I cannot use ArrayLists or the methods assoicated with them.

Any sort of help or push in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

The method should follow these instructions:

```
     - Adds an item to the list.  This method assumes that the list is already
      sorted in alphabetical order based on the names of the items in the list.

     - The new item will be inserted into the list in the appropriate place so
      that the list will remain alphabetized by names.

      In order to accommodate the new item, the internal array must be re-sized 
      so that it is one unit larger than it was before the call to this method.


public void add(Listable itemToAdd) {
         Listable[] items1;
         int newlength = items.length+1;
         items1 = new Listable [newlength];
         for(int i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
             items1[i] = items[i];
             items1[newlength-1] = itemToAdd;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a lazy way to do it, but why not add it to the end and re-sort? Sounds like a homework question :)

Comment: And there's the AVL tree approach, of course. Not sure it's the best solution either.

Comment: You are assigning `itemToAdd` to the last element of the array ever time you loop. Since the array is already sorted, can you think of a way to find where the item should be added in the array?

Answer (score 1):

That's not bad for a start! There are a number of things we need to do. This line

```
items1[newlength-1] = itemToAdd;
```

needs to come out of the loop, and be placed afterwards -- you'll set some array element to this value just once, yes, and not many times?

The copying part is a good start. What you need to do is

1. Find the location where the new element should go (search through the array, and find the element that the new one should go after)
2. Copy the elements that go *before* the new element
3. Copy the new element
4. Copy the elements that go *after* the new element (adjusting their indexes, since they're all one later than they used to be!)

Make sense?

Comment: That's the thing though, there's not a specified list of items that are in the array so I wouldn't exactly know where it goes.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, there's a better (and simpler) way of doing this.

Comment: @Sathish: You need to do comparisons to find out where an element should go. For example, compare the names of two items using the `compareTo` method.

Comment: So how would I implement the compareTo method in order to determine where the parameter would fit in the array?

Comment: `String` already has a suitable `compareTo()` method of its own.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a beginner class, you may have learned about [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). One of the interesting properties of insertion sort is that despite its poor runtime in the average case (*O(n<sup>2</sup>)*), its performance in the best case (a sorted list) is quite good - *O(n)*, in fact. An almost-sorted list would run in the same efficiency class. That might be a way to accomplish what you're trying to do. (It also might be one of the few places you'll ever use insertion sort, so make the most of it.)